# Pull only modified or changed files in git to jenkins workspace

Tags: git, jenkins

Currently several developers are pushing their code changes in same branch and we are using poll SCM method to get the changes for every 5 minutes.

Once the changes are done in the git along with the modified files all the other unchanged files also currently pushed to workspace. Is there any way to pull only modified files or delete the unchanged files older than certain time period ?

Answer (score 0):

> all the other unchanged files also currently pushed to workspace

Only if your job is set to clean up the workspace first (in which case, yes, all the files are copied all over again)

If not, you can start your job with a [`git clean -fd`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) in order to make your job start with a clean working tree.